# docker container with django gunicorn nginx

Tags: python, django, docker, nginx, gunicorn

I am trying to dockerize django using gunicorn and nginx into a docker image. from [this tutorial](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/web_development/9781838987428/1/ch01lvl1sec18/working-with-docker-containers-for-django-gunicorn-nginx-and-postgresql)

Running `docker-compose up --detach --build` Everything builds successfully. But gunicorn is not starting. Error log says:

> bash: /home/soccer/venv/bin/gunicorn:
> /Users/Umar/PycharmProjects/soccer/venv/bin/python: bad
> interpreter: No such file or directory

How can I fix this?

**Dockerfile:**

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.7

# accept arguments
ARG PIP_REQUIREMENTS=production.txt

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip setuptools

# create user for the Django project
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash soccer


# set current user
USER soccer

# set work directory
WORKDIR /home/soccer

# create and activate virtual environment
RUN python3 -m venv venv

# copy and install pip requirements
COPY --chown=soccer ./requirements /home/soccer/requirements/
RUN pip3 install -r /home/soccer/requirements/${PIP_REQUIREMENTS}

# copy Django project files
COPY --chown=soccer . /home/soccer/
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./config/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - static_volume:/home/soccer/static
      - media_volume:/home/soccer/media
    depends_on:
      - gunicorn

  gunicorn:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        PIP_REQUIREMENTS: "${PIP_REQUIREMENTS}"
    command: bash -c "/home/soccer/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 soccer.wsgi:application"
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/soccer/static
      - media_volume:/home/soccer/media
    expose:
      - "8000"
    environment:
      DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "${DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE}"
      DJANGO_SECRET_KEY: "${DJANGO_SECRET_KEY}"
      DATABASE_NAME: "${DATABASE_NAME}"
      DATABASE_USER: "${DATABASE_USER}"
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: "${DATABASE_PASSWORD}"

  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: "${DATABASE_NAME}"
      POSTGRES_USER: "${DATABASE_USER}"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "${DATABASE_PASSWORD}"
    ports:
      - 5432
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

Comment: Maybe you are overwriting something with the last copy statement. What is your .dockerignore file like?

Comment: I have no .dockerignore file

Comment: Yes it seems I was overwriting the venv. Now I added it to .dockerignore. But now docker container show nothing when pip list

Comment: Solved, I was installing to global env instead of virtual env

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. I was overwriting venv.  The solution is to add virtual env to .dockerinfo file.